# Tag for mononucleosis

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, Medical Sciences SE has tag [mono-mononucleosis](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mono-mononucleosis) with no approved synonyms.

Again, in order not to have [synonyms in tag names](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1203/12704), why not have tag [mononucleosis](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mononucleosis) with synonym [mono](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mono)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented as suggested, but [mono](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mono) will have to be upvoted by others to be created.